# Geofencing notifications not working in the background in Android

Tags: java, android, location, android-geofence

I have created a simple geofencing app that works fine when the app is in the foreground, but when the app `is in the background, I do not receive any notifications. I have started a foreground service and registered my geofences correctly. I have also granted my app the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. Any help would be appreciated.

**here is MapsActivity.java Code**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;
    private GeofenceHelper geofenceHelper;

    private final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 30;
    private final String GEOFENCE_ID = "SOME_GEOFENCE_ID";

    private final int FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 10001;
    private final int BACKGROUND_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 10002;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
        geofenceHelper = new GeofenceHelper(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng eiffel = new LatLng(48.8589, 2.29365);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(eiffel, 16));

        enableUserLocation();

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    private void enableUserLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Ask for permission
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                //We need to show user a dialog for displaying why the permission is needed and then ask for the permission...
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //We have the permission
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //We do not have the permission..

            }
        }

        if (requestCode == BACKGROUND_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //We have the permission
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can add geofences...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //We do not have the permission..
                Toast.makeText(this, "Background location access is neccessary for geofences to trigger...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            //We need background permission
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                handleMapLongClick(latLng);
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
                    //We show a dialog and ask for permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, BACKGROUND_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, BACKGROUND_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }

        } else {
            handleMapLongClick(latLng);
        }

    }

    private void handleMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        addMarker(latLng);
        addCircle(latLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
        addGeofence(latLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
    }

    private void addGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius) {

        Geofence geofence = geofenceHelper.getGeofence(GEOFENCE_ID, latLng, radius, Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = geofenceHelper.getGeofencingRequest(geofence);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = geofenceHelper.getPendingIntent();

        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Geofence Added...");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        String errorMessage = geofenceHelper.getErrorString(e);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void addMarker(LatLng latLng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    private void addCircle(LatLng latLng, float radius) {
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        circleOptions.center(latLng);
        circleOptions.radius(radius);
        circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        circleOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(64, 255, 0, 0));
        circleOptions.strokeWidth(4);
        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    }
}
```

**here is GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.java Code**

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceBroadcastReceiv";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Error receiving geofence event...");
            return;
        }

        List<Geofence> geofenceList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        for (Geofence geofence : geofenceList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + geofence.getRequestId());
        }
//        Location location = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
        int transitionType = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER", "", MapsActivity.class);
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL", "", MapsActivity.class);
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                Toast.makeText(context, "GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT", "", MapsActivity.class);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**here is GeofenceHelper.java Code**

```
public class GeofenceHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceHelper";
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public GeofenceHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .build();
    }

    public Geofence getGeofence(String ID, LatLng latLng, float radius, int transitionTypes) {
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
                .setRequestId(ID)
                .setTransitionTypes(transitionTypes)
                .setLoiteringDelay(5000)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .build();
    }

    public PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            return pendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2607, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        return pendingIntent;
    }

    public String getErrorString(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
            switch (apiException.getStatusCode()) {
                case GeofenceStatusCodes
                        .GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                    return "GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
                case GeofenceStatusCodes
                        .GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                    return "GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES";
                case GeofenceStatusCodes
                        .GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                    return "GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS";
            }
        }
        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

When app is in background or kill I want receive notification that user enter or exit  Geofence area  so how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Geofence transitions work better when the radius is 100 to 150m and above, its purely depend on the location point accuracy on which you are adding geofence.

In your case its 30m, too low as location accuracy may vary between 20 to 50m or above. If location accuracy is bad, you are going add a geofence far away from your actual location and miss initial trigger.

Make sure that you have the entry of GeofenceBroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml

setTransitionTypes - set all the required transitions
setTransitionType (Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

Set the radius between 100-150m, if its feasible for you.

All the best!